# how to make the value on Y axis start from zero in R, ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

currently, I'm using ggplot2 to make density plot.

```
ggplot(data=resultFile,aes(x=V19, colour=V1) ) +
geom_line(stat="density") +
xlab("score") +
ylab("density") +
ggtitle(paste(data_name,protocol,level,sep=" ")) +
theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position=c(0.92,0.9)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"),
                   labels=c("A", "B"))
```

using this code, I can get the plot below.
[image]

However, I can get different plot if I used plot(density()...) function in R.
[image]

Y value starts from 0.

How can I make the ggplot's plot as like plot(density()...) in R?

Comment: If you are using the `plot.default` function using base coding, you would need to specify the `xlim` argument as `xlim=c(0,##)` where the ## represents the maximum value you want to represent.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ggplot(data=resultFile,aes(x=V19, colour=V1) ) +
    ylim(0,range) #you can use this . 
    geom_line(stat="density") +
    xlab("score") +
   ylab("density") +
   ggtitle(paste(data_name,protocol,level,sep=" ")) +
   theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position=c(0.92,0.9)) +
   scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"),
   labels=c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` obviously cut off the x-axis at the min and max of the empirical distribution. You can extend the x-axis by adding `xlim` to the plot but please make sure that the plot does not exceed the theoretical limit of the distribution (in the example below, the theoretical limit is [0, 1], so there is not much reason to show outside the range).

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(x =runif(100)^3)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(temp, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(stat = "density" + xlim(-.2, 1.2)
plot(density(temp$x))
```